# AndroidSDK Hello World app giving an invalid format error when debugging on my MotoX?

Tags: android, motorola

I just started learning the android-SDK, I followed the basic steps to launch a hello world app, however I get this error in the LogCat:

```
06-06 17:53:49.203: E/Adreno-ES20(17462): <gl_external_unsized_fmt_to_sized:2379>: QCOM> format, datatype mismatch
06-06 17:53:49.203: E/Adreno-ES20(17462): <get_texture_formats:3009>: QCOM> Invalid format!
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/TgkFTtH.png]

I believe it might be a problem related to my Moto X that I am debugging on? I can see the app itself launching successfully on my phone, however I don't really understand this error so I don't know if it is a big problem or not, I was hoping someone could shed some light on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an OpenGL [bug](https://forums.motorola.com/posts/a8c64a0732) related to [Adreno GPU](https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/maximize-hardware/mobile-gaming-graphics-adreno/adreno-gpu) on your Moto X but it is in no way related to your application. So just ignore it and keep learning.